# Cofactor expansion does not apply to quaternion matrices?

Tags: determinant, quaternions

I'm doing question $1.5$ in Matrix Groups for Undergrads and I came across this question:

[image]

where equaton $1.5$ is given by

[image]

Here is the definition of $R_A$.

[image]

I can see why the map $R_A$ is not invertible, because I can choose my 'right' vector, $X$ as $(-a,a)$ for any $a \in \mathbb{H}$ and I would get the zero vector in return (based on def $1.10$).

However, isn't the determinant based on equation $1.5$ going to give me $ij-ij=0$. I don't see how I can show the determinant is **not** equals to zero.

Comment: Isn't the determinant $ij-ji$?

Comment: Oh right, you are correct! Thanks!